# Posting js variables to PHP not running in any method

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

In my JS code, I take in 3 inputs on a html page and save them to local storage. I then want to send these variables to php in order to save them to my database. No matter how hard I try no tutorial using ajax, jquery etc allows me to successfully post and echo variables from javascript in my php code. I see no reason why my code below doesn't echo the variables, but it doesn't.

Full code: https://codeshare.io/ayvK9e

Exact PHP elements (just trying to send normal variables right now as it still won't work"

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST as $post_var){
echo($post_var);
}
```

JS:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){
    const serverResponse = document.getElementById("serverResponse");
    serverResponse.innerHTML = this.responseText
};

xhr.open("POST", "eDBase.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("name=dominic&message=bumbaclaat");
```

Comment: Is the HTTP request successful otherwise? What do your browser's developer tools say about that?

Comment: the only error im getting is a random syntax error saying that there is an unexpected token '<' at eDBase.php.3

Comment: Can I have the code of eDbase.php please ?

Comment: Try this one : https://codeshare.io/aJ4r1r

Comment: HTML indexing file: https://codeshare.io/5Op3EP

Comment: eDBase.php file: https://codeshare.io/5XMAEM

Comment: @Dilek Code works, but its claiming the console output is due to my console.log, even after I removed the console.log first_name from writeFName function, it still claims its being output to console by the console.log under if(cfmf). Remove console.log from the code and see if the same happens for you

Comment: @cola465 I removed that html file you included into eDbase.php, because it was causing error parsing html.

Comment: your eDBase.php link is blank. Can we see that code please? Edit your question

Comment: @delboy1978uk here is total codes https://codeshare.io/24O7WA  php codes on the top is eDBase.php you can see in my answer too, and welcome :))

Answer (score 1):

If $post not work try using input php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

```
 let form = new FormData();
 form.append('name', 'dominic');
 form.append('message', 'bumbaclaat');

 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 xhr.open("POST", "eDBase.php");
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
       const serverResponse = document.getElementById("serverResponse");
       serverResponse.innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
    else console.log('error')
 };

 xhr.send(form);
```

Comment out the setRequestHeader to test it.

And at PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['message'];
}
else{
 echo 'There was a problem';
}
```

Comment: You missed out a ) and a ] from your if function. Aside from that still not working. Got these errors in console: https://gyazo.com/6bcb4d08afa41504c6fd2f94b4c2dbd8?token=07fc8d932eb01b7ba3ffb0906cf277b6 find both files above if you could read through the code would be appreciated.

Comment: oops, yeap(Updated). Aside from that. Check the previously declared code that you have for errors. All the errors you show to the screenshot have nothing to do with the code I've posted. Check your php for declared php tags. <?php  ...  ?> and already declared variables in your Javascript code

Comment: remove from the Head  <script src="eDBase.php"></script> You cannot add a php file like that into the document. The request alone will connect with the file.

Comment: No, he cant do that @NicolasVlachos because that page contains html in it, see php page in my answer, if he include that file into landing page he will have header already sent error. he is displaying results in two divs `<p id="email"></p><p id="serverResponse"></p>`

Comment: We're doing an asynchronous request to a file that handles the DB Insert.What the header has to do with the request alone. In the php file that will insert the data he will handle the request and the data attached to the form or the form data. He wants to INSERT data into the db as he says and then display them as response. You don't check if the request is indeed type of $_POST or the $_POST parameter exists neither you handle the values in your php code. A screenshot with errors from the  <script src="eDBase.php"></script> exists too. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexcpected token '<' eDBase.php :3

Answer (score 0):

When calling my function with the inputs onclick=showFunction; I was passing nothing to the function. In order for my values to be echoed in php I had to pass a parameter to the function onclick=function('text or variable'); IDK how I missed that.